# Which method to use for filtering out data from this json like output

Tags: python, json, regex, list

One of our systems provides me with data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "count": 1,
        "headings": [
            "name",
            "Hosts"
        ],
        "kind": "ApplicationInstance",
        "offset": 0,
        "results": [
            [
                "demo",
                [
                    "hostname2.domain.com",
                    "hostname3.domain.com",
                    "hostname4.domain.com",
                    "hostname1",
                    "hostname5",
                    "hostname7"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

This data is the result of a cURL command in a python script.

Now i'm trying to work out what would be the best method to fetch all of the hosts (including their domain name if they have any) that are part of "Demo".

Like this:

```
hostname2.domain.com
hostname3.domain.com
hostname4.domain.com
hostname1
hostname5
hostnam8
```

So far i have not been able to succeed with grep or regex, but i'm fairly confident that i'm not using it in the right way.

So i'm looking for your guidance in what would be the best approach solving this. Any of your pointers would be great.

Comment: `import requests; my_json = requests.get(endpoint).json()`. Now you have a python list. There is no need for regex, the JSON is valid and you just deserialize it to a nested python structure, which can be accessed as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the possible values of your JSON are, but here's a solution that works for the posted dictionary:

```py
import requests
hosts = []
resp = requests.get("URL") # if you want to get it from URL
for elem in resp.json(): 
    list_of_results = elem["results"] 
    for result in list_of_results: 
         if result[0] == "demo": 
             hosts.extends(result[1])


print(hosts)                                                                                                                                                                                                
# => ['hostname2.domain.com', 'hostname3.domain.com', 'hostname4.domain.com', 'hostname1', 'hostname5', 'hostname7']
```

If you're looking for a solution *just* for your posted JSON, then instead of using `requests.get`, you should use `json.loads`:

```py
import json

for elem in json.loads("JSON_STRING"):
    # same code
```

Comment: @roganjosh Edited just before your comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Adam, it does give me an error message:     list_of_results = res["results"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: That's because in my code, I treat `res` as a dictionary, and in your code it's a string. I'm guessing you haven't translated your JSON to a dictionary.

Comment: you are right! Translated the JSON to Dict and it works like a charm. Thanks for the expert help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json module or even the string fuctions.

with json module:

```
import json
with open('test.json') as json_f:
    data = json.load(json_f)
    for p in data:
        results = p['results']
        results = ((results[0])[1])

for res in results:
    print(res)
```